# Merge two data sets by date, filling in missing dates in 1st table, power bi

Tags: powerbi

I'd like to merge the two data sets by the date, keeping all the dates and filling in the totals col with NULL when the date doesn't match

EDIT: I’m working in Power BI

Data set 1

```
 dates      A_totals  
 2015-07-09     1
 2015-07-10     1   
 2015-07-12     2    
 2015-07-14     4   
 2015-07-16     0
```

Data set 2

```
 dates      B_totals  
 2015-07-09     2
 2015-07-11     5   
 2015-07-13     6    
 2015-07-15     9   
 2015-07-17     1
```

Desired Output

```
 dates      A_totals  B_totals 
 2015-07-09     1       2
 2015-07-10     1       null
 2015-07-11     null    5
 2015-07-12     2       null
 2015-07-13     null      6
 2015-07-14     4       null
 2015-07-15     null      9
 2015-07-16     0       null
 2015-07-17     null      1
```

Comment: You should be able to achieve this by simply merging the two tables using the `dates` column and using an outer join to do so.

Comment: @Oxbowerce When i do this, it creates empty date columns where data set 2 doesnt match data set 1 on the date

Comment: I'm not sure how you're doing it, but see my answer below for the exact code.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, this can simply be achieved by merging the two tables using the `dates` column as a key and using an outer join to make sure all rows from both dataframes are kept.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "dates": ["2015-07-09", "2015-07-10", "2015-07-12", "2015-07-14", "2015-07-16"],
    "A_totals": [1, 1, 3, 4, 0]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "dates": ["2015-07-09", "2015-07-11", "2015-07-13", "2015-07-15", "2015-07-17"],
    "B_totals": [2, 5, 6, 9, 1]
})

df1.merge(df2, how="outer", on="dates", sort=True)
```

This will return the following dataframe:

```
dates            A_totals  B_totals
2015-07-09       1.0       2.0
2015-07-10       1.0       NaN
2015-07-11       NaN       5.0
2015-07-12       3.0       NaN
2015-07-13       NaN       6.0
2015-07-14       4.0       NaN
2015-07-15       NaN       9.0
2015-07-16       0.0       NaN
2015-07-17       NaN       1.0
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in the title, I’m working in powerBI. If I’m asking this question in the wrong place, let me know. If there is a way to use Python or R to merge two data sets, that’d would be cool. My understanding is that the “Run (R/Python) script” will only work on the data set chosen when using Power Query Editor. I need to merge two separate sheets.

Comment: Apologies, assumes that you wanted to do this in Python. The process for doing this in PowerBI is almost the same, see [this example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/merge-queries-full-outer) from the Microsoft documentation. As the second to last step where you're expanding the second dataset make sure to also select the key column. You should then have two date column where some rows will be null, which you should be able to fill using simple if/else logic.

Comment: Unfortunately, this post you linked details the issue I have. When merging, that last row has null for the date rather than the date existing in the second table. If I merge via R or Python, this is not the case.

Comment: Can you maybe link a screenshot to shows what your current output in PowerBI looks like? In addition, are you selecting the date field from the second dataset when expanding it?